# Problems with globalization when using Oracle collections with thin JDBC

Tags: oracle, jdbc, localization, globalization

To summarise the issue:

1. Retrieving strings in Java 1.5 (JDBC) works fine when the DB encoding is Western ISO 8859-2
2. When switching to an Eastern European ISO (e.g. ISO 8859-5), all the normal JDBC string conversions work, **except the ones involving Oracle collections**, e.g. nested tables of objects. Instead of proper strings, even simple ones such as "1", I get "???" (three question marks) instead.

I tried the following 10.2.0.4 JDBC Jar files, but to no avail:

- ojdbc14.jar
- orai18n.jar

I also tried both CHAR and VARCHAR2 and both behave the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try using the type `NVARCHAR2`.

That type is better suited for non-English characters.

Comment: This is a good workaround, I've just thought of it a short while ago myself. Nevertheless, orai18n.jar should work, but I'm getting some strange errors. 

BTW, the characters in some of the strings which show up as "???" are just simple ASCII ones!